# how i can load a page in android WebView with cookies?

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, jsoup

i have cookies,want to send the cookie to WebView,how i can do?
i use JSOUP to get cookies from login page and i use the follow code but not working

```
webview.LoadUrl(URL, Cookies)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something like this a couple of weeks ago. I ditched the webview though and used a recyclerview for the info because of data and ram consumption.

```
res = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("user", user, "passwrd", pass)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();
String sessionId = res.cookie("PHPSESSID");
```

The code up there is actually from Jsoup's creator himself on how to store cookies. Then its a matter of setting the cookiemanager to these cookies.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie(url,String.format("%s=%s",
                        "PHPSESSID", sessionId));
```

Then I just loaded the webview. I think a really important line here is formatting the string in the second parameter of the `setCookie()` method to  match how the cookie is actually a **Map** with a key and value of **PHPSESSID** and the cookies characters. **PHPSESSID** is the id name that shows up for me in the cookie.